# Customer last logged in - Weird Date plus duplicate

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, customer-account

I am a bit confused about some of the information which is displayed under the personal information tab whilst viewing a customer in the admin

When looking at various customers I get something like the following

[image: Duplicate last logged in]

But also when looking at other customers I get something like

[image: Last logged - in weird year]

Questions:

1. Why is there 2 last Logged In's
2. Why sometimes does it not recongised a customer has logged in
3. What is the weird year "2882" in the 2nd image

Comment: No clue what happens. I assume this is some module. In my magento there is only one line and no time zone